# I got duplicate validation errors when use accepts_nested_attributes_for in both models. Could I avoid this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, accepts-nested-attributes

I have the following models:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
end
```

```rb
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, update_only: true

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

When I do the following steps:

```rb
company.name = nil
company.user
company.valid?
company.errors.full_messages
```

I get duplicate errors:

```
["Name can't be blank", "User company name can't be blank"]
```

Is there any universal way to avoid such behavior?

(Removing `accepts_nested_attributes_for` from one of the models is not the solution for me, and I need `.user` calling too)